# Mongify - MonogoDB _id Field Value Overwrites MySQL id Primary Key Field Values

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongify

I am using Mongify to convert MySQL data into MongoDB. However, I have `id` field in MySQL tables as `primary_key` but after mongify it overwrites with default MongoDB `_id` values i.e `"_id" : ObjectId("58369f006ee5c61b9400000e"),` I don't want to overwrite this I need exactly same value of `primary_key` in `id` column in MySQL into MongoDB `_id` something look like this:

**MySQL** `id: 123` should convert into **MongoDB** as `"_id" : ObjectId("123"),`

here is my translation file of of users table

```
table "users" do
  column "id", :key, :as => :integer
  column "username", :string
  column "password", :string
  column "email", :string
  column "first_name", :string
  column "last_name", :string
  column "dob", :date
  column "gender", :boolean
  column "status", :integer
  column "created", :datetime
  column "modified", :datetime
```

`end`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the workaround which was already there in Mongify [docs](https://github.com/anlek/mongify)

**Add This**

```
before_save do |row|
row._id = row.delete('pre_mongified_id')
end
```

So the complete transaltion script for `users` table would look like

```
table "users" do
  before_save do |row|
    row._id = row.delete('pre_mongified_id')
  end
  column "id", :key, :as => :integer
  column "username", :string
  column "password", :string
  column "email", :string
  column "first_name", :string
  column "last_name", :string
  column "dob", :date
  column "gender", :boolean
  column "status", :integer
  column "created", :datetime
  column "modified", :datetime
end
```

Thanks anyways.